# What shape of merkle tree does the Bitcoin client build?

Tags: block, merkle-tree

The Bitcoin client builds a merkle tree to represent the transactions, then includes the root of that tree in the block header.
[image: merkle tree from bitcoin paper]
But usually, the number of transactions is not a power of two. When that happens, how does the Bitcoin client represent the transactions in the tree?

If I wrote a custom mining client, which built a tree with a different "shape," (example below) what would happen?

[image: custom merkle tree]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### When the number of transactions is not a power of two, how does the Bitcoin client represent the transactions?

Each time around, it hashes each transaction with the one next to it, until there's only one left.
[image: 2 transactions merkle tree example]
If there's an odd number of transactions, the last one is hashed again.
[image: 3 transactions merkle tree example]
In this example, we start out with 11, then 6, then 3, then 2, then 1.
[image: 11 transactions merkle tree example]

#### What would happen if you made a differently-shaped merkle-tree?

When sending blocks around, there's no way to specify the shape of the merkle tree. If it's different, the standard client will just reject it.

Comment: Small correction: when there are an odd number of elements in a level, the last one is hashed after appending it to itself. So usually hash6 of one level is H(hash12+hash13) of the level below, but it can be H(hash12+hash12) if hash12 is the last one.

Comment: @PieterWuille Huh. I hadn't noticed that. +1